# Do Google Apps Standard (free) accounts expire after a period of inactivity?

Tags: google-workspace

I have a Google Apps Standard account for a seldom used domain. The domain is mine indefinitely (the Registrar offers this to locally registered charities - I just have to maintain a basic webpage), but the group it was intended for never actually formed.

The group may still organise someday, and I would like to keep the account active. I'd like to know how often I need to sign in to the admin console to keep the free account active. I don't sign in very often, maybe once a year or so.

Will this expire someday, and what are the minimum requirements to keep it active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not (or rather, Google has not expired them yet).  I have Google Apps accounts from the very first beta that are not actively used but I can still log in to the Administrator Panel and control the account.  I have gone years in between logins, so there does not appear to be a time limit.

No one knows what Google will do in the future though.

Comment: Ahh, that's great news!